# without looping twice in the list of dictionaries how can one be altered based on a value of keys in another

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have an array of dictionaries all of them with the same set of keys. How can I efficiently change the value of one of the dict based on the value in another. THe array is long and there are many keys but this small example will clarify the question.

A = [ {F:[0, 10], G:[1,11], H:[2, 21]} ..... {F:[20, 21], G:[31, 41], H:[42, 63]}]

Now I could do this

```
for x in A:
   if x['F'][0] == 20:
      x['H'].append(31)
      for y in A:
         if y['f'][0] == 0:
            y['H'].append(31)
```

These are long lists with dicts with several keys so is there a better way to do this?

Appreciate your response.

Thanks

Comment: your code will append 31 to the inner_dict['H'] as many times as there are preceding `inner_dict['F'][0] == 0`. Is that what you really want?

Comment: yes. but in reality I will not have more than one because the first value in the F keys array is unique